# How to use native ipv6 together with 6to4? I got lost packets

Tags: linux, networking, routing, linux-networking, ipv6

I've found that I can't run native IPV6 interface (at eth0) with 6to4 tunnel (at tun6to4) together.

Here's my setup (/etc/network/interfaces/):

```
auto eth0
auto bond0

iface eth0 inet static
    address 57.164.26.201
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 57.164.26.0
    broadcast 57.164.26.255
    gateway 57.164.26.254

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2001:5f45:2:1973::2
    netmask 64
    post-up /sbin/ip -6 r add default via 2001:5f45:2:19ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0

iface bond0 inet static
    address 57.164.25.173
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

when I ping6 -I eth0 google.com - I got:

```
PING google.com(iad23s40-in-x0e.1e100.net) from 2001:5f45:2:1973::3 eth0: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from iad23s40-in-x0e.1e100.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=81.1 ms
64 bytes from iad23s40-in-x0e.1e100.net: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=81.1 ms
64 bytes from iad23s40-in-x0e.1e100.net: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=81.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s40-in-x0e.1e100.net: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=81.0 ms
64 bytes from iad23s40-in-x0e.1e100.net: icmp_seq=5 ttl=55 time=81.0 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 81.082/81.099/81.123/0.312 ms
```

After I run this:

```
/sbin/ip tunnel add tun6to4 mode sit ttl 62 remote any local 57.164.25.173
/sbin/ip link set dev tun6to4 up
/sbin/ip -6 addr add 2002:39a4:19ad::1/16 dev tun6to4
/sbin/ip -6 route add 2000::/3 via ::192.88.99.1 dev tun6to4 metric 1
```

I got 100% packet loss on both IPV6 interface's pings (though sometimes few packets reach google's ipv6..).

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6=0
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.autoconf=1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra_defrtr=1
```

I've found this script in /etc/network/if-up.d/ipv6-routes

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script sets up the IPv6 connectivity by setting the default route.
# Matching entries in /etc/network/interfaces might not work when the boot
# process is parallelized, because eth0 is not up
# quickly enough.
[ -n "${ADDRFAM}" -a "${ADDRFAM}" != 'inet6' ] && exit 0
[ -n "${IFACE}" -a "${IFACE}" != "eth0" ] && exit 0
sleep 5
/sbin/ip -family inet6 route add 2001:5f45:2:19ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0
/sbin/ip -family inet6 route add default via 2001:5f45:2:19ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
exit 0
```

Seems that various different routes make such situation happen that none work correct.
How can I solve it? Please, help.
Running Debian 7 Wheezy.

**EDIT:**
I've found a simple solution for 6to4:
/etc/network/interfaces/

```
auto 6to4
iface 6to4 inet6 6to4
        local 57.164.25.173
ifup 6to4
```

And after ifup 6to4 in console I run this:

```
echo "200 sixtofour" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip -6 rule add from 2002::/16 table sixtofour
ip -6 route add 2002::/16 dev 6to4 table sixtofour
ip -6 route add default via ::192.88.99.1 dev 6to4 table sixtofour
```

After that both Native and 6to4 ipv6 interfaces can finally ping6 google.com ...

But.. it looks like not the end. I've got a little % (from 0 to 3-5 or even 10-12 % in some attempts) of packet loss on any of ipv6 interface. In some ping6 tests it runs really smooth and without any error, but sometimes I got 1 from 10-11 packets lost.
I know that my 6to4 performance very much depends on multiple public 6to4 relays on the internet for anycast address, so it's almost impossible to find out which relay might be causing packet loss.. And it may be really better way to switch for tunnel broker. But I also know that there are people who use both ipv6 tunnel brokers and 6to4 interfaces at the same time AND there are even a lot more COMPLEX setups with various additional devices.

Seems that network routing in linux is very important for such setups and I'm kinda newbie in it.

**BTW:** what I've also found

```
Interrupt:20 Memory:fe500000-fe520000
```

line in eth0, when I run ifconfig in console.

I just hope that there could be few things left to fix it like:

- changing TTL;
- adding routing table for eth0 ipv6 interface
- running ndppd;

and/or a "little" more?

I really appreciate any help.

**END OF PART2. To be continued**

Comment: You can't solve this. 6to4 is broken: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7526

Comment: That's sad..
I've found only one similar problem (packet loss on multiple ipv6) here - https://www.sixxs.net/forum/?msg=setup-2401309 - but it look's like different problem.
Or maybe I may try to fix it with iptables too?

Comment: I meant to say - make changes in routing table, not iptables. Going to learn about it, but not sure, if it will help in my case.

Comment: It might be possible to determine this if you post the contents of `ip -6 route`, but I really can't think of any reason to do this.

Comment: No problem:
ip -6 route
2001:5f45:2:1900::/56 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  expires 2591965sec
default via fe80::205:73ff:fea0:1 dev eth0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 1765sec

Answer (score 3):

Try using a 6in4 tunnel broker to get IPv6 connectivity.  It is more reliable and will work in this case.  The brokers I am aware of offer free tunnels.

The upgrade is quick and relatively painless.  I've been using 6in4 over with IPv6 on eth0 for years.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I was interested if I should try tunnel broker's too. I'll write back when I'll try.

Comment: tunnelbroker.net is the last big one, since sixxs stopped accepting new signups last year.